# Stop countdown timer if user wins game

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

I'm working on a kid's game that involves a countdown timer. If a user matches all elements before the timer runs out, a "You Won!" popup appears. If they do not match all elements before the timer hits zero, a "Sorry, You Lost" popup appears.

The issue I'm having is that the clock doesn't stop counting down after a user wins the game and the "You Won!" popup appears, so the "Sorry, You Lost" popup still appears once the timer reaches zero.

Here is my code:

```
$("#startClock").click( function(){
   var timer;
   var counter = 4;
   var winner = 0;
   var done = true;

   $("#boat").draggable({
    revert: "invalid", containment: "#wrapper",
    start: function(event, ui){
        if(!done) return false;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui){
        if($(".correct").length == $(".drop").length){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("<div title='You did it!'>You won!</div>").dialog();
            },500);
            var winner = 1;
        }
    }
    });

    if(!timer){
      timer = setInterval(function() {
         counter--;
         if (counter >= 0) {
           span = document.getElementById("count");
           span.innerHTML = counter;
         }
         if (counter === 0 && winner === 0) {
           $("<div title='Game Over'>Sorry, game over!</div>").dialog();
           clearInterval(counter);
         }
       }, 1000);
    }
});
```

[View my demo game here.](http://spanishforkidsbykids.com/playa/demo/) (Click "Start the Clock" in the top right corner.) Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Lauren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call clearInterval() on the reference of setTimeout.

```
var timer;
    $("#startClock").click( function(){
       var counter = 60;
       if(!timer){
          timer = setInterval(function() {
         counter--;
          if (counter >= 0) {
             span = document.getElementById("count");
             span.innerHTML = counter;
          }
          if (counter === 0) {
             $("Sorry, you lost!").dialog();
             clearInterval(timer);
           }
         }, 1000);
       }
    });
```

Also add a call to clearInterval(timer) when the user wins the game, but first check if timer is defined.

Comment: I appreciate the help! I just updated my code in my initial post, as well as the code in the demo game I posted. I'm still having an issue with making the clock stop when a user wins the game. I'm a beginner at this and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but any further help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You need to call clearInterval with a reference of the timer clearInterval(timer).

Comment: Hi @Lauren I tried the page and the timer stops when you won and when you win, it's seems ok o.o

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the code for when the player wins, but you would need to explicitly stop the counter when the payer wins. An else if would work for that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is probably just to add a `&&` to your second condition to check if the player has won the game. EDIT - also add an else to clear timer if player has won.

```
if (counter === 0 && /*check if player has not won*/) {
  $("Sorry, you lost!").dialog();
  clearInterval(counter);
}
else if (/*if player has won*/) {
  clearInterval(counter);
```

This way the 'sorry you lost' message will only appear if the timer runs out and they haven't yet won. If you're not already doing so, you could create a variable that changes if the player wins and check the value of that variable in the second half of the above condition.

Comment: I tried implementing the following, but it just prevents the "you lost" popup from appearing. Any ideas?

`if (counter === 0 && document.getElementByID("goodJob").css("display","block"))`

Comment: Yeah, sorry I thought the main goal was to prevent pop-up, but if you also add an else condition you can stop the timer when someone wins. I'll edit above code to show. Eduardo has the write idea above too.

Comment: Oh you want to know how to check if a player has won too. If you post the code that shows how your code displays the 'you win' text too I can help you figure it out. But basically you want set a variable `playerWon` to 0 and then change it to 1 if the player wins. Then the above condition will just be `if(counter ===0 && playerWon === 0)`. Make sense?

Comment: I tried to implement the code you listed, but I'm having an issue with the "you lose" popup not displaying at all.

You can try clicking "Start the Clock" at the top right of this demo page: http://spanishforkidsbykids.com/playa/demo/

Any ideas? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi  @Lauren can you show us the code that you are using to display the You Lose popup in the console it appears a message of a toggle error.

Comment: Hi @Eduardo-Quintana I listed my "You Lose" popup code in my initial message. I also edited my initial message to include my "You Win" code. I'm using dialog boxes to display this information. Thanks!